# Vim like jump-to-word in Sublime Text

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

I'm not very familiar with vim, but there's a particular feature I really like.

The `/` search command.

Type `/` and then your string of text, ex: `/text`
And your cursor will be moved to the beginning of the first occurrence of that word.

Sublime Text has `ctrl+;` but that's not really what I'm looking for, it selects words and it doesn't start from where the cursor currently is.

Is there anything like this for Sublime Text, either a plugin or a keybinding that I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I found a package that does just this right.

It's on package control and it's called `jumpTo`

Use `ctrl+e` (I rebound it to `ctrl+shift+/` because of Emmets `ctrl+e` binding) to start searching. It works perfectly.

If you want to select the word as wel, use `ctrl+shift+e`

Edit: Actually, no it's not the same, it only searches in the current line of text. To make it look from your current cursor position to to end of the file, get the source and look for the line

`line = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(pt, lr.b))` (line 27)

and replace it with

`line = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(pt, self.view.size()))`